# Multi-threading. Exception in thread

Tags: python, multithreading, exception

I'm trying to understand with an [example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/index.html). Here's the code:

```
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2
import time
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

hosts = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://amazon.com",
"http://ibm.com", "http://apple.com"]

queue = Queue.Queue()
out_queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, queue, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            host = self.queue.get()

            #grabs urls of hosts and then grabs chunk of webpage
            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            chunk = url.read()

            #place chunk into out queue
            self.out_queue.put(chunk)

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

class DatamineThread(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, out_queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.out_queue = out_queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            chunk = self.out_queue.get()

            #parse the chunk
            soup = BeautifulSoup(chunk)
            print soup.findAll(['title'])

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.out_queue.task_done()

start = time.time()
def main():

    #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance
    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue, out_queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    #populate queue with data
    for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

    for i in range(5):
        dt = DatamineThread(out_queue)
        dt.setDaemon(True)
        dt.start()


    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed
    queue.join()
    out_queue.join()

main()
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

Sometimes I get this error here:

Exception in thread Thread-10 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown)

Explain please what caused it.

**Update by another author:**

Here's the full exception I see in similar code:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
  File "mine.py", line 86, in run
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/Queue.py", line 168, in get
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 237, in wait
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Some ideas how people might be more willing to help you:  1. Explain what you have done to diagnose the problem and why your efforts failed. 2. Try to reduce the code to the minimum necessary for the error to occur. 3. Give the full traceback of the error.

Comment: I see the same error in similar code.  I'll add my full exception above.

Comment: I find this error occasionally when I am using the multiprocessing.Pool class. It seems to be from the daemon threads it creates still being operational when the interpreter starts deleting things during shutdown. A solution which, if it has not solved it, it has lessened the frequency below my observation threshold is to make a call to pool.terminate() or similar when you are done with the multi-processing.

Answer (score 4):

That is bug http://bugs.python.org/issue14623

The most simple workaround is to add timeout

```
time.sleep(1)
```

in the end of script that allows the threads to finish before the script comes to end of life and close

Comment: Or better yet, keep track of all the threads started and call `t.join()` on them to make sure they've properly exited and are cleaned up.

Answer (score 1):

Your example script seems okay - which is to say, it runs fine for me using python 2.7.2.

What version of python are you using? It's possible the errors you're seeing may be related to [this bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1722344). If so, then upgrading to python>=2.6.5 or python>=3.1 might help.

Comment: I get a similar problem with python 2.7:Exception in thread Thread-9429:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 756, in run
    self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable